# Realm observe with UICollectionView - race conditions

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, realm

I am using `Realm` as a caching layer so that whenever data is presented to the user, it is first fetched from the database and displayed to the user. Subsequently, a server request is sent to fetch the newest version of the data, sync it with the `Realm` database and display the changes in a `UICollectionView`.

The problem is that when the cached data is retrieved from the `Realm` database and the `UICollectionView` is getting updated, there is a chance that the server request for update finished before the `UICollectionView` loaded all the cells and since the `Results` list is a live collection of data, it could have been modified. Now for example, if an item was removed on the server-side, the live collection would hold one item less and therefore cause out of bounds exception.

This being said, even the code provided in official `Realm` documentation is not thread-safe considering the fact that the `results` can be changed while the `UITableView` is asking for each row one by one:

```
class ViewController: UITableViewController {
    var notificationToken: NotificationToken? = nil

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let realm = try! Realm()
        let results = realm.objects(Person.self).filter("age > 5")

        // Observe Results Notifications
        notificationToken = results.observe { [weak self] (changes: RealmCollectionChange) in
            guard let tableView = self?.tableView else { return }
            switch changes {
            case .initial:
                // Results are now populated and can be accessed without blocking the UI
                tableView.reloadData()
            case .update(_, let deletions, let insertions, let modifications):
                // Query results have changed, so apply them to the UITableView
                tableView.beginUpdates()
                tableView.insertRows(at: insertions.map({ IndexPath(row: $0, section: 0) }),
                                     with: .automatic)
                tableView.deleteRows(at: deletions.map({ IndexPath(row: $0, section: 0)}),
                                     with: .automatic)
                tableView.reloadRows(at: modifications.map({ IndexPath(row: $0, section: 0) }),
                                     with: .automatic)
                tableView.endUpdates()
            case .error(let error):
                // An error occurred while opening the Realm file on the background worker thread
                fatalError("\(error)")
            }
        }
    }

    deinit {
        notificationToken?.invalidate()
    }
}
```

The only way I can think of fixing this is to create a deep copy of the results as well as synchronize the body of the observe function using Semaphore or similar to make sure the data will not get in an inconsistent state, which I consider very inefficient. (Note that `tableView.endUpdates()` does not mean the `UITableView` has reloaded all the data, however it is just dispatched to a queue and ready to be processed in async.)

I would like to hear any suggestions how to implement this in an efficient way such that the mentioned race conditions are eliminated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do all of your UI updates on the main thread.  If you do this an the first sets of results updates the collection view on the main thread, when the next set of results also comes it it will be queued on the main thread so it updates after the first set is done.

Comment: It is right that the actual UICollectionView updates will be done serially since they are on the same thread, however the actual data collection can be changed regardless already during the first update as it is modified from a background thread.

Answer (score 0):

Based on:

> The problem is that when the cached data is retrieved from the Realm database and the UICollectionView is getting updated, there is a chance that the server request for update finished before the UICollectionView loaded all the cells and since the Results list is a live collection of data, it could have been modified.

I do not think that that will happen, since as soon as your live collection will be changed update notification will be triggered and collection will be rebuild/updated accordingly. However, as I said you in PM it was some time ago when I worked with realm.

It is quite easy to test your hypothesis: decrease speed of your simulator's internet, or make huge table, etc. I am really curious if you can actually create a problem which you think you will have.

Comment: I actually happen like 1/10 times since I have the server running locally.

Comment: Hmm, and after it happens (collection view is loading, live collection was changed) what happens next? Doesn't collection view triggers an update for updating it's values?

Comment: The observer will trigger another UICollectionView update (the update switch case) which is dispatched to the queue on the main thread (so no problem here). Yet, the initial update is not finished and as the collection view is asking for each cell one by one but for instance one item was removed from the data so it results in index out of bounds.

Comment: In your collection view you implemented numberOfItems(inSection: Int) -> Int, right? And you connected it to lenght of your live collection, right?

May you share your UICollectionView implementation?